# How can I wrap my input with commas when I'm creating new scripts based on what the user does?

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery:

```
var script4 = document.createElement("script");
script4.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script4.innerHTML = '$(document).delegate("#Filterable_Value2' + count + 
'","keyup",function(){ var input = $("#Filterable_Value2' + count + 
'").val(); document.getElementById("Filter_Value2-' + count + '").innerHTML = 
input;})'; 
document.head.appendChild(script4);
```

I'm creating a jquery script based on if a users clicks the +. 
This way I cannot use ' or " otherwise I'll break the "script".

How can I make it work that the last input has 'input'?

Comment: Aside from the issue, why not just put the delegated event handler directly in your code without this, rather ugly, script tag injection.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I never develop things myself started with this today

Comment: I mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zesyvac4/. Note that it uses a single event handler on all the appended content using `on()` (which is preferable over `delegate()` as the latter is now deprecated). It then uses DOM traversal to find the related element to update on `keyup` instead of using incremental id attributes, which should be avoided where possible.